# Scheduled items logic with days and time offset

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset

I have inside the database a "Schedule" class with 3 columns:

**start** (number) - **slots** (array) - **day** (number)

[image]

For example, the element in the circle refer to this row:

start: 1

slots: [1,2]

day: 3

When I have to save a scheduled item, I select the parameters and save:

[image]

**The problem occurs with a time offset.**

For example, in this case, I send the minutes difference (-120)  between local time and the server time (UTC) to save the item in UTC format.

Then the item is saved in the day Tuesday (2) instead of Wednesday (3) and this creates many problems in the management of the table in the front end and in the code.

I believe it is correct save the data in utc format, but in the front end how can I handle this (Tuesday instead of Wednesday)?

I did not use Date objects, I'm wrong?

I did lots of tests, for example, this code (dirty) work with local time:

```
function generateLocalScheduleInfo(day, start, end) {

    var startDate = new Date();

    //Set the date to the next input day (day)
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (day + (7 - startDate.getDay())) % 7);
    startDate.setMinutes(0);
    startDate.setSeconds(0);
    startDate.setHours(start);

    var startSlot = startDate.getHours();
    var endSlot = end;
    var slots = [];

    if (startSlot <= endSlot) {

        for (var i = startSlot; i <= endSlot; i++) {
            slots.push(i);
        }

    } else {

        var hoursBeforeMidnight = 24 - startSlot

        var hoursAfterMidnight = endSlot + 1;

        var numberOfHours = hoursBeforeMidnight + hoursAfterMidnight;

        for (var ii = 0; ii < numberOfHours; ii++) {

            if (ii < hoursBeforeMidnight) {

                slots.push(startSlot + ii);

            } else {

                slots.push(ii - hoursBeforeMidnight);

            }
        }
    }

    var dict = {
        "day": startDate.getDay(),
        "startAtHour": startSlot,
        "slots": slots
    };

    return dict;

}

var startSlot = 1;
var endSlot = 2;
var day = 0;

var scheduledInfo = generateLocalScheduleInfo(day, startSlot, endSlot);

console.log(scheduledInfo);
```

I need a more simple solution for this

Thanks

Comment: Prepare for a world of hurt that is time in JavaScript. Use Moment.js and their timezone library to ease your suffering.

Comment: if you are dealing with complex dates/timezones/timeoffsets, use the excellent [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library